How to make the relative line number shift one character to the left as vscode does in intellij?
I am now using Intellij IDE like pycharm and ideavim plugin, i have the：
set number relativenumber

inside the .ideavimrc to have the relative number like this:
but i am wondering if i can make it easier to check like vscode, which shift the absolute line number one character left, like this:

Thanks！

Just use ideavim's issue tracker.

Thanks for making the page looks better!
I may add my suggestions on YouTrack.
